# Android ndk file .so. How run file .so

Tags: android, android-ndk

I have file libFFmpeg.so. but it is into "\src\main\jniLibs\armeabi"
When run device with cpu x86. it is crash app. i have to copy libFFmpeg.so to x86,but it is still crash. Can you help me? I can build to x86, min, armeabi...

Answer (score 1):

You need to build a version of the libFFmpeg.so that supports x86. When using the NDK a different .so file is required for each ABI.

Here are some instructions on building FFMPEG for x86 https://software.intel.com/en-us/android/blogs/2013/12/06/building-ffmpeg-for-android-on-x86

Comment: Can you send link have build success?  I am start developer. :9

Comment: @Nhu While building the FFMPEG library yourself can be a long process you will need to do it to ensure the module is the same for all architectures (ARM, x86). You will also need to build it yourself to ensure you are building with the correct switches to comply with FFMPEG licensing. Please do some research and take the time to understand the FFMPEG licensing considerations.

Answer (score 0):

https://axdxy.wodemo.com/browse/378008/lib/x86/libffmpeg.so
I have to found libs. can you download from web before.